# Sails.js Catch All Route + Passport

Tags: angular, sails.js, passport.js

I am using Sails.js and Angular 2. I want to use the default HTML5 path strategy with Angular 2. To do that with an Express server, which I've done before, I need to have every route that doesn't have to do with an api call to return the homepage view. So in express, it'd be something like this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

I know this works, because I'm currently using it in another project. With this, when I go to `domain.com/some/route` the server returns the proper view. If you don't have the wildcard for the route, it can't match the URL and won't return anything. On my other project, I'm also using authentication middleware that checks for a JWT on every API call, but not the index call. That way the Angular 2 app can handle login and still show something.

With that being said, I figured the Sails.js way would be similar. The difference here is we're using OpenID Connect and that server is on its own and authentication is done there. I have routes configured in `config/routes.js`, and they work great when I have the following route (which returns the homepage layout view) at the top of the list:

`'/': 'HomeController.index'`

Then when the path matches that exactly it returns the right view. But with that my Angular 2 app needs to use the Hash Location strategy. I tried moving that route to the bottom of the routes list and changing it to:

`'/*': 'HomeController.index'`

But then when my app tries to authorize by using passport-openidconnect, I get an error in the browser saying that the browser has redirected too many times. Nothing shows up in the terminal, and I'm not even hitting the auth server or the callback function for after the authorization is done.

I thought this would be simple; me just following the [directions explained here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#/about-route-ordering), but they aren't working. Has anyone else had this same issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like passport is taking precedence and doing some redirecting of its own-- probably because it's installed in your HTTP middleware (see config/http.js) or in a policy that is protecting `HomeController.index`.  If you temporarily comment out Passport, my guess is that everything will work as expected. Assuming that's true, then you'll want to dig into where the redirect loop is coming from (either in passport or in some other application logic or policy).

One thing to watch out for, in particular: if Passport is installed in a policy, then you'll want to make sure that policy is not set up to protect your catchall route.

> Also, be aware that you'll probably want to add `skipAssets: true` to your catchall route so that you're able to serve CSS, images, etc. -- unless you have all of those hosted elsewhere (but even then, you'll want to consider `favicon.ico`, `robots.txt`, and `sitemap.xml`).

Comment: This does seem to be the problem, but now that I designated the policies to be on a per controller basis, like this: `AuthController: { '*': 'policyName' }`, for some reason the policy is not hit before it tries to go into the controller. So I get to a controller action and am not logged in and it's not liking that. I've debugged through it and the controller action is hit before policy is hit.